# Is this failing radio button feature test a Capybara syntax issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, model, capybara

I have a form with a radio button for a boolean attr `prev_cover`, displays Yes or No in browser with param values of true or false and saved in db as true or false as data type boolean. I am trying to:

- a) model test presence of a selection of the radio buttons
- b) feature test the creation of a whole quote record.

With validation of `prev_cover` in place, I tell capybara to `within(".quote_prev_cover") { choose('No') }` the create_quote_spec test fails, model quote.rb test passes.

With validation of `prev_cover` in place, I tell capybara to `within(".quote_prev_cover") { choose('Yes') }` the create_quote_spec test passes, model quote.rb test passes.

In actual manual browser testing the db record is created when either Yes or No is selected.

When I remove presence validation of prev_cover from quote.rb the create_quote_spec passes with with prev_cover Yes or No selected, but of course the model quote_spec.rb test fails.

I cannot see where the problem is here, is it something to do with the capybara `within(".quote_prev_cover") { choose('No') }` syntax perhaps? (it finds that css element just fine)

Here's form element of new.html.erb

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <%= simple_form_for @quote do |f| %> 
                <%= f.input :prev_cover, as: :radio_buttons, label: "Previous cover" %>
                <%= f.submit "Get quote", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's quote.rb validation;

```
validates :prev_cover, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
```

Here's `prev_cover` element of the called NewQuoteFrom.new being created by Capybara;

```
within(".quote_prev_cover") { choose('No') }
```

Here's test that fails if chooses prev_cover 'No' and passes if chooses 'Yes', create_quote_spec.rb

```
feature 'creating quote request' do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:new_quote_form) { NewQuoteForm.new }

before do
    login_as(user, :scope => :user) 
end

scenario 'completing quote data' do
    new_quote_form.visit_page.fill_in_with().submit
    expect(page).to have_content('Quote request created')
end
```

here's the model test that passes whilst model validation is present, quote_spec.rb;

```
    context 'previous cover' do
        it 'must be true or false' do
            quote = Quote.new(prev_cover: nil)
            quote.valid?
            expect(quote.errors[:prev_cover]).not_to be_empty
        end 
    end
```

Failing test message:

```
1) creating quote request completing quote data
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Quote request created')
   expected to find text "Quote request created" in "Toggle navigation QuoteEngine My Quotes My Account Sign out Complete the below to get a quote * GLA Previous coverYesNois not included in the list * Company name * Company number * Postcode * Industry Financial services Architect Business consultancy Lives overseasYesNo Scheme start date 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 January February March April May June July August September October November December 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 Payment frequency Annually Monthly Commission level"
 # ./spec/features/create_quote_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Note the `YesNois not included in the list` in the error message, using any variation of true or false in the Capybara instruction does not work either.

Even specifying:

```
<%= f.input :prev_cover, as: :radio_buttons, :collection => [['Yes', true],
                                    ['No', false]], label: "Previous cover" %>
```

in the simpl_form_for in the new.html.erb view still results in the failure with the validation giving `Previous coverYesNois not included in the list`!?

Even `within(".quote_prev_cover") { choose('quote_prev_cover_false') }` still fails with the same `Previous coverYesNois not included in the list`.

It passes if told to choose Yes `within(".quote_prev_cover") { choose('Yes') }`, almost asif I hadn't already changed from `presence:` to `inclusion:` which I most certainly have done.

Actual HTML from firefox inspector:

```
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional quote_prev_cover">
  <label class="control-label radio_buttons optional">Previous cover</label>
    <input name="quote[prev_cover]" value="" type="hidden">
        <span class="radio">
            <label for="quote_prev_cover_true">
                <input class="radio_buttons optional" value="true" name="quote[prev_cover]" id="quote_prev_cover_true" type="radio">Yes</label>
        </span>
        <span class="radio">
            <label for="quote_prev_cover_false">
                <input class="radio_buttons optional" readonly="readonly" value="false" name="quote[prev_cover]" id="quote_prev_cover_false" type="radio">No</label>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: In the future posting the actual error messages (and lines they come from)  when tests fail would be a good idea

Comment: Please show the actual HTML for the relevant controls (not the ERB template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue causing the failure of this Capybara test trying to create a quote record was that it was unable to select the No/false value of a boolean radio button, which due to a simple_form bug had `readonly="readonly"` set. There are two solutions, courtesy of this post [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1257)

1) Within config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb comment out `b.optional :readonly` within the `:vertical_radio_and_checkboxes` wrapper.

2) set your simple form arguments as below:

```
<%= f.input :prev_cover, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['Yes', true], 
                        ['No', false]], readonly: nil %>
```

Though option 2 still has Capybara giving you a warning when you run your tests of; `Attempt to set readonly element with value: true * This will raise an exception in a future version of Capybara`

Thanks to #ThomasWalpole helping me along the way and to platformatec maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this report makes sense is if your statement "In actual manual browser testing the db record is created when either Yes or No is selected with corresponding boolean values created just fine." isn't true.

That's because you're using `validates_presence_of` (through validates presence:{...} shortcut) validator which can't be used with boolean fields if `false` is a valid response.  From the `validates_presence_of` docs

> If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the
>   real values are true and false), you will want to use
>   validates_inclusion_of :field_name, in: [true, false].
>
> This is due to the way Object#blank? handles boolean values:
>   false.blank? # => true.

Therefore, if you change from presence validation to

```
validates :prev_cover, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
```

your tests will probably pass.

Comment: Spot on Thomas, whilst using `validates_presence_of` it was saving if I selected Yes, but not with No. Now using your advised `inclusion:` I can manually save, however strangeley the `within(".quote_prev_cover") { choose('No') }` capybara is still stopping the test passing, with the error message as above in main question body.

Comment: @jdk We need to see the relevant actual HTML (not the erb template) and the contents of the params submitted (in your test.log) to figure anything else out.  You might as well also specify what driver you're using for these tests.

Comment: Updated as above. I am using Capybara and RSpec out of the box, gemfile pasted above.

Comment: No other driver specified, so is using :rack_test I believe.

Comment: @jdk The part of test.log that would be helpful is the part when the POST is done for the submission (so we can see what parameters are actually submitted) - although the fact that the 'No' option radio button is readonly probably means that's not being selected and submitted.

Comment: How strange, this is just a simple_form_for from gem simple_form, writtem as follows `<%= f.input :prev_cover, as: :radio_buttons, label: "Previous cover" %>`, any idea why the false/no would be automatically set as read only and the true/yes would not?

Comment: @jdk It has to have something to do with how you've defined your model.  If you haven't specified `readonly` as an option to simple_form then it attempts to determine it from your model - https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/components/readonly.rb

Comment: Hmm, strange, defined as a boolean; `t.boolean  "prev_cover"`.

Comment: Wow, changed to; `<%= f.input :prev_cover, as: :radio_buttons, :readonly => false, label: "Previous cover" %>` and still the No radio button has `readonly="readonly"` :(. Why only the false/no button too?! Possibly helpful; https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1257

Comment: @jbk You really have no other references to `:prev_cover` in your model?  If not, then you probably need to use a debugger (byebug for instance) and step through the code and see why `readonly` is being added to that element

Comment: Definitely only one prev_cover attr in the model, set as boolean.

Comment: @jbk That's not what I was asking. What other references to it do you have in your model file (quote.rb or whatever) ?  Obviously there is the `validates` reference, do you not have any other references to it?

Comment: No other references to prev_cover anywhere in the model. Wow this is a bug, details and solution placed in the main question body. Woah, phew, pleased to find this one, thanks for the guidance on the journey #ThomasWalpole.